# for loop pagination prints page result as 'num.0'

Tags: python

code below is a part of web scraper and it prints page numbers as `page number.0`

How to remove that .0 and only print page numbers?

```
for page in range(0, 1040, 20):
    print(f'===== Page {(page/20)+1} =====')

# print result  ===== Page 1.0 =====
```

Comment: Use integer division `page//20`

Comment: @Barmar Oh!! It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dividing automatically makes the result turn into a Float type even if "page" was set as an int() type prior.
Add the int() method in print to convert it into an integer.

```
print(f'===== Page {int((page/20)+1)} =====')
```

Comment: Converting the whole string with `====` won't work.

Comment: I edited my previous answer. I meant to add the int within the brackets and not outside of the string.

Comment: @BullSupreme It's ok, I'm a beginner, I appreciate all help. thanks